# How to implement multiple packages in main.dart in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am developing one app in flutter-android, for that, I am using screenUtil package and also I am checking device connection status(internet). Now my main.dart code is below where I have initialized screenUtil

```
void main() => (runApp(new MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScreenUtilInit(
      designSize: Size(360, 690),
      allowFontScaling: false,
      builder: () => MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: HomeScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the code I need to use in my main.dart to get the connection status across my widgets:

```
void main() => (runApp(new MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return StreamProvider<ConnectivityStatus>(
    builder: (context) => ConnectivityService().connectionStatusController,
    child: MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomeScreen(),
    ),
  );
}
```

How can I use both the codes in my main.dart file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example : internet connection check programmatically in flutter.

You can sync with my code.

like these my source code below in details. just copy and past then modify with yours code
it is main.dart file:

```
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';

void main() => (runApp(new MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScreenUtilInit(
      designSize: Size(360, 690),
      builder: () => MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: HomeScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  var connectionStatus="";
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    checkConnection();

  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(connectionStatus),
      ),
    );
  }
  void checkConnection() async{
    var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
    if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
      // I am connected to a mobile network.
      // write your code here;
      connectionStatus="mobile data";
    } else if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
      // I am connected to a wifi network.
      // write your code here
      connectionStatus="wifi data";
    } else {
// where your code here
      connectionStatus="no internet connection";
    }
  }
}
```

and my pubspec.yaml file

```
name: flutter_app
description: A new Flutter application.
version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_screenutil: ^5.0.0
  data_connection_checker: ^0.3.4
  connectivity: ^3.0.2
  connectivity_platform_interface: ^2.0.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

best of luck!

Comment: thanks for the help.. how can we implement this dynamically? like when I am in the app (offline) and the internet got connected, it should show online. for this we need to have listeners/Streams.. something like that.. can you help regarding this implementation @Md Omar Faruqe